# How do you send an array as part of an (jquery) ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, servlets

I tried to send an array as part of an ajax request like this:

```
var query = [];
// in between I add some values to 'query'
$.ajax({
    url: "MyServlet", 
    data: query,
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function(noOfResults) { 
    alert(noOfResults); 
    }
  });
}
```

I wanted to see what I get back in the servlet, so I used this line:

```
System.out.println(request.getParameterMap().toString());
```

Which returned `{}` suggesting an empty map.

Firebug tells me I am getting a `400 bad request` error

If I send a queryString like `attribute=value` as the 'data' then everything works fine, so it has to do with not being able to send an array as is. What do I have to do to get that data into the servlet for further processing. I don't want to pull it out and turn it into a queryString in the JS if I can avoid it.

**EDIT:** I used the .serializeArray() (jQuery) function before sending the data. I don't get the 400 but nothing useful is being sent through.

Comment: What does `query` contain? (strings / objects?). If you pass an array to `data`, jQuery assumes it is in the format: `[{ name: 'name', value: 'Jim' },{ name: 'age', value: '20' }]`.

Comment: Each array value is supposed to be another array of objects - but for now I am just trying to get a simple example to work, similar to what you have there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to send an object which you first stringify with JSON.stringify.

like this:

```
var query = [];
// in between I add some values to 'query'
$.ajax({
    url: "MyServlet",
    data: JSON.stringify({ nameParameter: query })
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(noOfResults) {
        alert(noOfResults);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Note that not all browsers include the `JSON` library. You should include the `json2` library: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: It didn't seem to work. But that could be due to an error elsewhere. I am going to try the method suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: I should refresh my browser more often! Thanks for the extra info Matt

Comment: I should add, that once the json2.js file is included, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to send the data as name/value pair (which is expected). Like

```
var query = ["data1","data2"];
// in between I add some values to 'query'
$.ajax({
    url: "MyServlet", 
    data: {'query' : query},
    success: function(noOfResults) { 
    alert(noOfResults); 
    }
  });
}
```

You should get the data at server side like this

```
query => Array ( [0] => data1 [1] => data2 )
```

As per the jQuery documentation for `data` setting of `jQuery.Ajax()` method

> If value is an Array, jQuery
>   serializes multiple values with same
>   key based on the value of the
>   traditional setting

Comment: If the `data` parameter is not a string, jQuery uses the `jQuery.param` method to serialize it; if `jQuery.param` receives an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by .serializeArray(). (`[{name:"first",value:"Rick"},
{name:"last",value:"Astley"},
{name:"job",value:"Rock Star"}]`); http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param